# MYSQL query to get records with value that increased most between two dates

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table `ScoreArchive` with following fields:

`ID` (int), primary key

`Date` (date)

`Score` (int)

I record in the table the `Score` of each `ID` every day.

Now I wish to find the IDs that have the top *score increase* between, for example, 2011-04-22 and 2011-05-31.

How can I find these using a MySQL query?

Answer (score 4):

Try something like:

```
select id, max(score) - min(score) as diff ... group by id order by diff desc
```

---

Edit (following up on the comment):

Or something like:

```
select id, final_scores.score - start_scores.score as diff
from (
   select id, min(date) as min_date, max(date) as max_date
   from scores
   where date between ...
   group by id
   ) as ranges
join scores as final_scores
on final_scores.date = ranges.min_date
join scores as start_scores
on start_scores.date = ranges.max_date
where ...
order by diff desc
```

Comment: This might not work if the score does not monotonously increase every day.

Comment: Very true. Edited to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks, though I am getting an error "Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous"

Comment: disambiguate it, e.g. `ranges.id`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT score FROM ScoreArchive WHERE date BETWEEN 2011-04-22 AND 2011-05-31 ORDER BY score DESC;
```

That's how i would do it in pgsql i am guessing that mysql is the same